# Editing the hover and normal state of button with css (Failed attempts)

Tags: html, css

I have been stuggling to change the color of the button of the contact form placed at the end of the website

I inspected with the google chrome and it says the `btn.btn.button-primary`

I tried finding button-primary and edited it as follows:

```
/* @primary button theme
-------------------------------------------- */
.smart-forms .btn-primary {  background-color: #18cfab;  }
.smart-forms .btn-primary:hover,
.smart-forms .btn-primary:focus { background-color: #18cfab; }
.smart-forms .btn-primary:active{ background-color: #283033; }
.smart-forms .btn-primary, 
.smart-forms .btn-primary:hover { color: #283033; },
.smart-forms .btn-primary:focus { color: #283033; }, 
.smart-forms .btn-primary:active{ color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08); }
```

HTML:

```
echo '<div class="section">';
echo '<div class="smart-widget sm-left sml-120">';
echo '<label class="field">';
echo '<input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha" class="gui-input sfcode" maxlength="6" placeholder="Enter CAPTCHA">';
echo '</label>';
echo '<label class="button captcode">';
echo '<img src="' . plugins_url('php/quote/captcha/captcha.php?<?php echo time();?>', __FILE__). '" id="captchax" alt="captcha">';
echo '<span class="refresh-captcha"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></span>';
echo '</label>';
echo '</div>'; 
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="result"></div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="form-footer">';
echo '<button type="submit" data-btntext-sending="Sending..." class="button btn-primary">Send Message</button>';
echo '<button type="reset" class="button"> Cancel </button>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</form>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

I want the main color to be `#18cfab` and hover color to be `283033`.

Can anyone pinpoint the mistake and a better approach to catch the tag and edit accordingly

Thanks

Comment: Don't see any issue with your CSS. probably something is overriding your style. Could you inspect and check?

Comment: Second and third last line of your css end in a comma. This indicates a selector group of which nothing is specified first. This is invalid. 

If a browser encounters an invalid member in a group, it is not allowed to use its style.

Comment: This is PHP - not HTML :)

Comment: what you have inside echos is  HTML, not PHP. PHP is only a transporter of HTML and cannot do much to output without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your code but with better indentation and enhanced readability:

```
.smart-forms .btn-primary {
  background-color: #18cfab;
}
.smart-forms .btn-primary:hover, .smart-forms .btn-primary:focus {
  background-color: #18cfab;
}
.smart-forms .btn-primary:active {
  background-color: #283033;
}
.smart-forms .btn-primary, .smart-forms .btn-primary:hover {
  color: #283033;
},
.smart-forms .btn-primary:focus {
  color: #283033;
}, 
.smart-forms .btn-primary:active {
  color:       #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
```

Now I can point out many mistakes:

- There are extra commas after some CSS rules.
- You have declared `.smart-forms .btn-primary:hover` twice: Once you have set the color as `#18cfab` and on the next declaration you have set it to `#283033`. The second declaration will overrule the first in this case.

The modified code will look like this:

```
.smart-forms .btn-primary {
  color:            #283033;
  background-color: #18cfab;
}
.smart-forms .btn-primary:hover, .smart-forms .btn-primary:focus {
  color:            #fff;
  background-color: #18cfab;
}
.smart-forms .btn-primary:active {
  text-shadow:      0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  color:            #fff;
  background-color: #283033;
}
```

Comment: it worked after i deleted my browser history. Can you also modify the code to give white text on button when it hovers?

Comment: did it anyway. Thanlks

Comment: Code modified. Now button text changes to white on hover.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the smart-forms css file is overriding your custom style. With that in mind you could use `!important`, as mentioned above, or add the element to the class which will hopefully work.

If the element is always going to be a button this will work.

```
.smart-forms button.btn-primary {
   background: #18cfab;
}

.smart-forms button.btn-primary:focus,
.smart-forms button.btn-primary:hover {
    background: #283033; 
}
```

Alternatively you could try with an extra descendant.

```
.smart-wrap .smart-forms .btn-primary {
   background: #18cfab;
}

.smart-wrap .smart-forms .btn-primary:focus,
.smart-wrap .smart-forms .btn-primary:hover {
    background: #283033; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)
To debug / check CSS

Update:

You have a class selector for `.smart-forms` in your original CSS while that class is not used by the parent of the button. The one used is actually the id `#smart-form`

### **Snippet Updated**

This *should work*, unless it's being **overwritten**.

if not, provide more code / html

```css
#smart-form button.button.btn-primary {
  background: #18cfab;
}
#smart-form button.button.btn-primary:hover {
  background: #283033;
}
```

Comment: should be with hash in the start?

Comment: What is the use of a snippet containing CSS only?